# Unable to do transformation of findbugs xml reports due to integration issue with findsecbugs plugin

Tags: source-code, opensource

I am trying to integrate the find-security-bugs plugin for findbugs using maven. I am able to run findbugs with maven and perform transformation from xml to html without any issue. I am able to run findbugs with findsecbugs plugin without transformation. I am encountering error when I am trying to do transformation after configuration of findsecbugs plugin. The problem is arising coz the findsecbugs plugin is landing up in the xmloutput directory somehow and the error comes when trying to transform the jar file when it is expecting a XML file.

My config looks like below:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <phase>process-resources</phase>
         <configuration>
           <target>
              <echo message="${project.version}" file="${project.build.directory}/version"/>
           </target>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
           <goal>run</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${findbugs.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
            <effort>Max</effort>
            <!-- Build doesn't fail if problems are found -->
            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            <!-- Reports all bugs (other values are medium and max) -->
            <threshold>Low</threshold>
            <!-- Produces XML report -->
            <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
            <!-- Configures the directory in which the XML report is created -->
            <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
            <includeFilterFile>./dev-support/findbugsIncludeFile.xml</includeFilterFile>
    <!--Configure include and exclude filters here -->
    <includeFilterFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/findbugs-security-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
            <excludeFilterFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/findbugs-security-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.h3xstream.findsecbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findsecbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.3</version> <!-- Auto-update to the latest stable -->
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
            <!--
                Ensures that FindBugs inspects source code when project is compiled.
            -->
        <execution>
            <id>analyze-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <transformationSets>
                <transformationSet>
                    <!-- Configures the source directory of XML files. -->
                    <dir>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</dir>
                    <!-- Configures the directory in which the FindBugs report is written.-->
                    <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</outputDir>
                    <!-- Selects the used stylesheet. -->
                    <!-- <stylesheet>fancy-hist.xsl</stylesheet> -->
                    <stylesheet>default.xsl</stylesheet>
                    <!--<stylesheet>plain.xsl</stylesheet>-->
                    <!--<stylesheet>fancy.xsl</stylesheet>-->
                    <!--<stylesheet>summary.xsl</stylesheet>-->
                    <fileMappers>
                        <!-- Configures the file extension of the output files. -->
                        <fileMapper
                                implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                            <targetExtension>.html</targetExtension>
                        </fileMapper>
                    </fileMappers>
                </transformationSet>
            </transformationSets>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <!-- Ensures that the XSLT transformation is run when the project is compiled. -->
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>transform</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Edit:
The error looks like below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0:transform (default) on project test1: Failed to transform input file <UserHome>/test1/target/findbugs/findsecbugs-plugin-1.4.3.jar: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Content is not allowed in prolog. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: A quick fix is to set an [exclude](https://maven.apache.org/jxr/maven-jxr-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html). I'd say this question is off-topic for this site. Some tool questions are on-topic, but this would be more suited to the a findbugs mailing list.

Comment: That exclude list is for which files to scan. This transformation is about converting the output XML file into HTML. I have searched extensively before putting this question here. I feel this may be related to configure Maven correctly as well, but if someone has faced similar issue, they can post the solution here. Rest as your wish.

Comment: I meant an exclude on xml-maven-plugin - check the link in my original comment.

Comment: I went at the link and added below lines, with no effect on problem.
"<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/findsecbugs*.jar</exclude>
                </excludes>
                </configuration>
      </plugin> "

Comment: Within your existing <transformationSet> tag, try adding <excludes>*.jar</excludes> If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I'm unable to help you further

Comment: Sure, I will try that. Also took your advice and subscribed to findbugs mailing list. If your suggested fix doesn't work, will write to the mailing list. I appreciate your time and help. Thanks @paj28.